# Inheritence - How to structure a Parent class with Children

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

So I am working on this project, and I am having trouble on how to structure this. Basically, this is what I have:

Main Class instansiates Listener Class.

Listener class listens for packets.

When I packet is recieved, the Listener class creates a new instance of the Handler class (which is a runnable). The Handler class then reads the packet data and determines the packet type (reboot, shutdown, etc) and does what it needs with it.

What I want to do, is have a parent class Packet, and then have subclasses with all the different packet types RebootPacket, ShutdownPacket, etc.

I was going to just use tons of IF statements in the Handler class to create instances of the packet classes (if packetType = "reboot", RebootPacket packet = new RebootPacket) however, I feel that there should be a better way to do this. Could I some how use polymorphism to do this? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Im not sure what a Packet is in your case, but im guessing you're sending data over a network? When the object comes in, the best way to go about it is either use `instanceof` or check if the class type == what you're looking for

Comment: @VinceEmigh Well the actual data sent over the network is just text, as in a string...

Comment: Why not use an Object streams? It seems as if thats what you want to do anyways. If you're using blocking io, `ObjectOutputStream` is able to send any object that implements `Serializable`. If not, then yes, you need to check the String value to see what you need to create

Comment: @VinceEmigh The data is being sent by a PHP client, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of your problem, please correct me if I am wrong:

You are being fed data in "packets" which are really just Strings.  These packets can have multiple types, and each type of packet has a different action associated with it.  Each time a packet is read in, a new instance of the Handler class is created, which does what it needs to with the packet, depending on type.  I am going to assume that the type of packet is inherent to the input.

In this case, I would suggest using polymorphism.  I would create one method to do each of the 'actions' associated with individual types of packets.  Each of these methods would have identical method signatures, except the parameter would be of a different type.  For example:

```
public void doSomething(RebootPacket p)
```

and

```
public void doSomething(ShutDownPacket p)
```

This could be done for every packet type you will use.  What this allows you to do is simply call `doSomething(packet)` and have it handle the packet in the correct way, regardless of type.

I suggest not using inheritance in this situation.  When you have a subclass and a superclass, you want the subclass to have all or most of the same methods as the superclass, plus some of its own that the superclass cannot have.  It seems to me like there aren't many methods which all of the packets would have in common, but rather a different way of handling each.  If this is a correct assumption, polymorphism makes the most sense.  If not, please comment with more information.

Comment: How would I assign the packet to a class? Would I just need if statments?

Comment: If statements would be the easiest way.  However, if you are going to need to use a large block of if statements in the first place, I don't see why you can't use the same if statements to call the proper methods.

Comment: Well I mean, thats what I am doing now, lots of if statements and then calling the method, but I feel like thats very unorganized, everything shoved into one class, etc.

Comment: No matter what you do, it seems to me as if you will need to use a large block of if statements to assign these packets to their proper type.  Depending on the amount of work you need to with each packet and their similarity, it may or may not make sense to use different classes for each one.  That is for you to decide.  But if it is only one or tow methods per packet, I would be inclined to simply keep the block of if statements.